# How to monkey patch class instance variable in pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, monkeypatching

I have a class that have a variable in `__init__` and a method. The variable stores a string value that represents the s3 bucket name, which will be used by the method.

```py
class Manage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bucket = 'doc'

    def read_file(self):
        bucket = self.bucket
        ...
        return file
```

And I am writing a test case to test the method but the problem is I want to use a different bucket, so I want to patch the value of that variable.

Code I tried

```py
import Manage

def test_manage(monkeypath):
   monkeypath.setattr(Manage, 'bucket', 'doc2')
   ...
```

The above code is not working, since the bucket is not a class-level variable (i guess). I don't know how should I change that

Comment: set it after you initiate the object?

Answer (score 0):

As @gold_cy suggested, you can set it after instantiating the object:

```py
import Manage

def test_manage():
    manage = Manage()
    manage.bucket = 'doc2'
   ...
```